# Dependence between components of a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $\det{J}=0$?

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

(I'm not sure the title describes the question adequately... edits are welcome)

Given a map
$F(x,y)=(f(x,y), g(x,y))$,

such that, in some neighborhood of $(x_0, y_0)$, the following conditions hold:

- $f,g \in C^1$
- $|J_F(x,y)| \equiv 0 $
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \ne 0 $

Prove that there exists a function $h$ which is continuously differntiable in some neighborhood of $f(x_0, y_0)$, such that
$g(x,y)=h(f(x,y))$ in some neighborhood of $(x_0, y_0)$.

Guidance is to show that $g$ is independent of $y$ and depends only on x using an implicit function $x=\Phi(f(x,y), y)$ that exist in some neighborhood of $(x_0, y_0)$.

My attempts at a solution:

1. From the zero determinant of the Jacobian I can show that the derivatives of $g$ are linearly dependent on the derivatives of $f$ at every point.
2. Per the guidance, I can show that an implicit function $x=\Phi(f(x,y), y)$ exists (implicit function theorem conditions hold).

I'm stuck at this point... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess by $J_F$ you mean the determinant of the Jacobian matrix. Personally, I use the notation $J_F = [\partial_x F| \partial_y F]$ in this context. So, the determinant of $J_F$ is, since $F = (f,g)$, $\text{det}(J_F) = \partial_x f\partial_y g - \partial_x g\partial_y f$. Of course, in calculus III in a typical US university we only encounter the determinant of the Jacobian which is often called the Jacobian. Hence the term Jacobian matrix is helpful.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks

Comment: I read this again, and I just feel like something is missing. I'm not sure what, but certainly $g$ is not just a function of $y$ in that $g(x,y) = h(f(x,y))$ so unless $f$ is also not a function of $y$ this is hard to understand.